# How do you use the Update.Set() with a Property of Type List<> in MongoDB(c#)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class like as

```
 class RiskAlertSettings
{
    public object _id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<RiskAlertType> Alert { get; set; }
    public string EmailList { get; set; }
    public string SMTPClient { get; set; }
    public string SMSList { get; set; }
    public string SoundType { get; set; }
}
```

I inserted Data sucessfully.But while updating am getting error.
My query is

```
riskAlertSettings.Update(Query.EQ("UserName", settings.UserName), Update.Set("Alert",settings.Alert));
```

I got errors as

```
The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
```

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'

Can any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert your list to a Bson type, most likely an array.  Just wrap

```
new BsonArray(settings.Alert)
```

around your list, thusly.

```
riskAlertSettings.Update(Query.EQ("UserName", settings.UserName), 
    Update.Set("Alert",new BsonArray(settings.Alert)));
```

BsonArray class is in the MongoDB.Bson namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SetWrapped<T>(name:String, value:T)` in the `MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update` class. Then you don't have to create a BsonArray specifically in update scenarios.